# Flutter Duration_Picker Package not working properly with ColorScheme(brightness.dark)

Tags: flutter, dart, duration

So like the title says when I use the Duration_Picker package specifically the `showDurationPicker` with `brightness.dark`, the text on the widget doesn't show like in the picture below. However, everything works fine with `brightness.light`.

Code:

```
Duration? dur = await showDurationPicker(
                          context: context, initialTime: duration);
```

App Screenshot with brightness.dark :

[image]

App Screenshot with brightness.light :

[image]

Edit: Might I add that this wasn't an issue before. I put the project on stall and after a couple months I came back to this. If this  is an issue with the package itself, please suggest an alternative. Thank you!